# Android Phonegap application can't connect to internet

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, getjson

I made a simple android application in phone gap,jQuery mobile, HTML5 with a simple getJSON data encoding . The application working well in Browser . But not in android .

When googled I found that android cant connect to internet . So that I added the following

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But Still my application doesn't getting jSON data .. In browser its working well

my js file looks like

```
    function getMovies(){


var serviceURL = "http://myserver.com/";


alert("TEST"); // THIS WILL WORK ON BROWSER AND APPLICATION


        $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'movies.php?jsoncallback=?',null, function(data) {


    alert(data.result); // THIS WILLL WORK ON BROWSER

            var movies=data.result;

            $.each(movies, function(index, movie) {

                $('#movielist ul').append(
                    '<li><div class="image"></div><div class="content">'+
    '<div class="moviename">'+movie.movie+'</div>'+
    '<div class="moviedetails">Description</div>'+
    '</div></li>'


                );



            });

        });     




    }
```

my PHP code in server looks like

```
 $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM filims");
$result=array();

$i=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$result[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
$result[$i]['movie']=$row['movie'];
//$result[$i]['image']=$row['image'];
$i++;


}


$output=array();

$output['result']=$result;
$output['error']=0;
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'('.json_encode($output).')';
```

my AndroidManifest.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.phonegap.helloworld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-feature />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".App"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"> <intent-filter> </intent-filter> </activity> 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Plese help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: your manifest file is ok. it has all permissions. just check if the wifi is on. if still it doesnt work i suggest u try this once instead of getJson http://www.freelancephp.net/simpleajax-small-ajax-javascript-object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `myserver.com` or `*` to the `ExternalHosts` option in the `PhoneGap.plist`

Comment: Your answer is for iOS. The OP said they are using an android application