# How to enable certain Internet connection in Android app?

Tags: android, cordova

How to enable my phonegap app to access certain type of connection at a time.  So the user may select either of:

1. Connect via Wi-Fi
2. Connect via Mobile Data

And use that for connecting to external resources.
any idea. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346861/android-phone-gap-application-connets-to-internet  this might help

Comment: thanks for the link. but i was trying to figure out what should I do to make it possible for user to active any one. So if user choose Mobile data then app shouldn't use wifi. how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this programatically within the app but you can present the user with a button to open wireless settings so they can enable/disable one or the other.

That's covered here: [Ask user to start WiFi or 3G on launching an android app if not connected to Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456428/ask-user-to-start-wifi-or-3g-on-launching-an-android-app-if-not-connected-to-int)

Also, it is possible to restrict apps from using mobile data and force them to use only WiFi in the Android settings menu. Go to Settings -> Data Usage -> Select the app -> Restrict Background Data. This will only allow the app to use WiFi data and the restriction is at the OS level.

I hope these help!